# Underline all text in a row of an R dataframe

Tags: r, shiny, datatable, shinydashboard

I'm building a shiny app and I want to emphasize a summary row in some of my dataTable outputs. I would like all the values in the second to last row to be underlined. I'm not strong enough with HTML or CSS to know where to start with this. I've looked through a bunch of DT style guides but can't find anything helpful

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can paste an underline tag around the entries you want to underline, then set `escape = FALSE` in `DT`.

- `escape` property in `DT`: https://rstudio.github.io/DT/ see section 2.10 Escaping Table Content
- Example of adding tags around some content: `paste0("<u>", "original content", "</u>")`